# CSS selector with link without target attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've two types of links

```
<a href="url">Internal Link</a>
```

and

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">External Link</a>
```

I'm able to use css on external link using:

```
a[target="_blank"]
```

But I don't know how to select with css all link without "target=_blank" attribute.

I try with `a[target="_self"]` but It not works because target attribute is not present in the "internal link".

Comment: Hello, why not simply go with `a {}` if you are going to overwrite the one with a target attribute ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `:not`  selector

```css
a[target="_blank"] {
  color: green;
}

a:not([target="_blank"]) {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="url" target="_blank">External Link</a> 
</p>
<p>
    <a href="url">Internal Link</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:not` selector see [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)

However, it might be easier to give either a class or a ID to your link instead. Writing the style for a class/element will give you finer control over each element.

HTML
`<a id="someid" href="https://link.com" />`

CSS
`#someid {color: red}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()` selector as per the other answers, or you can just make CSS *specificity* work for you:

- Use `a {}` selector to target all anchor elements
- Now use `a[target=_blank] {}` to target the *external links*

Now the `a {}` selector will work for *those* selectors that are *not* external.

```css
a[target="_blank"] {
  color: green;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="url">Internal Link</a>
<a href="url" target="_blank">External Link</a>
```